# How to use persistenceJS in phonegap application?

Tags: html, mobile, cordova

We are building a field data collection tool that will be available in *two versions*:

1. Fully **html5** -- directly
   downloadable through your browser
   (does not support camera access,
   etc..).
2. Hybrid using **[phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/)** --
   installation required (does support
   camera access, etc..).

In the html5 version we are using 
[persistenceJS](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs) to store data. Somehow this does not seem to work in the hybrid version and it would be nice to keep the code base as generic as possible.

Does anyone know about using **persistenceJS  in combination with phonegap?**

*Note 2011/04/04: In a prototype we have gotten persistenceJS to work in phoneGap. Probably some kind of library is interfering in some way.*

Comment: could you share whether the problem is resolved or not and if yes then how??

Comment: It looks like it is the browser websql size limitation. I have turned it down to 4MB which solved the problem for now.

Comment: thanks Timo. I am using persistenceJS in a mobile web and phonegap app, in both i have set the database size to 5MB. no problems yet.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap is kind to persistencejs.

The only potential trouble is with iOS, which made its websql storage non-persitent starting in iOS 5. In other words your database can be periodically removed by the operating system.

If you upgrade to Phonegap 1.6 and up, there is a built-in fix for this problem and your persistencejs will work just fine.